# Prove the group statement.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that G is a group with identity element e. Let α, β, γ ∈ G be arbitrary. Prove the following
statements.

(i) $abc=e$ implies $bca$ = e.

(ii) $bac= a^{-1}$

imply $cab = a^{-1}$.

I want to use (Inverses:Every permutation $f \in S_n$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$ such that $ff^{-1}=id=f^{-1}f.$) to prove. Is this right? But I am confused about how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the existence of inverses. For example, starting with the equation $\alpha \beta \gamma = e$, we can multiply from the left with the inverse of alpha to get $$\beta \gamma = e \cdot \beta \gamma = \alpha^{-1} \alpha \beta \gamma = \alpha^{-1} \cdot e = \alpha^{-1}.$$
This way we already have $\beta \gamma$ on the left hand side and in the correct order. Can you continue and get $\alpha$ on the right of $\beta \gamma$?

The second statement can be done similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Both are similar so i will show you how to do the first:

Assume $abc =e$ then multiplying by $a^{-1} $ from the left we get

$bc=a^{-1}$ and now multiplying by $a$ from the right we get

$bca = e$ as wanted.